# I cannot find location of some basic class in Python

Tags: python, reflection

I have a problem that seems very ungooglable.

There is a `compile` function in Python.

`c = compile('6', 'ff', 'exec')`

The result of this is a class named `code`.

```
>>> c.__class__
<class 'code'>
```

I wanted to make a comprison to detect a type, but I can't find a module with this class. Naturally I could code it like this:

`if type(unknown_object) == some_codeobj.__class__:`

But it's not very elegant. Does anyone knows, where I can find the class?

Comment: What's the context here - what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

`types.CodeType`

Even though it's stdlib, the code behind it is quite hacky:

```
def _f(): pass
CodeType = type(_f.__code__)
```